# Lower and upper bounds of eigenvalues of the solution $P=P^T>0$ of the Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, control-theory, stability-theory

Consider a Lyapunov equation
$$
PA + A^TP = -Q
$$
where $A$ is stable and $Q = Q^T\ge0$.
It is well known that if $Q>0$ (i.e., positive definite), then there are close relations between eigenvalues of $A$, $P$, and $Q$.
For example, [Lancaster](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1012104) showed the inequalities:
$$
\frac{m(Q)}{|m(A+A^*)|} \le m(P) \le \frac{M(Q)}{2|m(A)|},\\
\frac{m(Q)}{2|M(A)|} \le M(P) \le \frac{M(Q)}{|M(A+A^*|}
$$
where $m(A)$ and $M(A)$ are the minimum and the maximum of the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$, respectively.

Now, assume that $Q = C^TC\ge0$ and $(A,C)$ is observable.
We still have a unique solution $P = P^T>0$ of the Lyapunov equation.
I am wondering if we have inequalities similar to the one shown above in this case.
Specifically, I am wondering if the lower bound of $m(P)$ and the upper bound of $M(P)$ can be written by using $A$ and $C$.
Any help would be appreciated.

## Edit

Probably, it would be better to show one of my trials.
The solution $P$ can be written as
$$
P = \int_0^\infty e^{tA^T}C^TCe^{tA}dt.
$$
Since $P>0$, there exists $x\neq0$ such that
$$
m(P) = \frac{x^TPx}{x^Tx} = \int_0^\infty\frac{\|Ce^{tA}x\|^2}{\|x\|^2}dt > 0.
$$
Thus, I may need to find a lower bound of $\|Ce^{tA}x\|$ by using $A$, $C$, and $\|x\|$; this is the point I was stuck.
Since $C$ is not assumed to have full rank, I may need to use the property that $(A,C)$ is observable but do not have any idea so far...

Comment: The bounds obtained by Peter Lancaster remain valid when Q=C^TC and $(A,C)$ is observable. In that case, however, the lower bounds on both the minimum and maximum eigenvalues are both zero. Are you interested in the lower bounds on the eigenvalues?